# Minimum Symfony Routing Usage

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, routes

I am trying to get a minimum Symfony routing system together to run on the side of my Laravel install for the incoming APIs to be outside the full Laravel install. I noticed that our normal Laravel system includes 575 files to render / load and it just is too slow to handle the incoming workload. More details here: https://serverfault.com/questions/959018/apache-tuning-for-512gb-ram

To put it together I made up a new composer file named `minvendor.json` with the following:

```
{
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "minvendor"
    },
    "require": {
        "symfony/routing": "^4.2",
        "symfony/http-foundation": "^4.2",
        "symfony/yaml": "^4.2",
        "symfony/config": "^4.2"
    }
}
```

Since there is already a `composer.json` file, you have to use a different command to load the `minvendor.json` file.

```
env COMPOSER=minvendor.json composer install
```

I then put the following into the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^api api.php [L]
```

After that I made the `api.php` file with the following

```
<?PHP
require __DIR__.'/../minvendor/autoload.php';
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\YamlFileLoader;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;


$fileLocator = new FileLocator([__DIR__]);
$loader = new YamlFileLoader($fileLocator);
$routes = $loader->load('routes.yaml');

class LuckyController
{
    public function number()
    {
        $number = random_int(0, 100);

        return new Response(
            '<html><body>Lucky number: '.$number.'</body></html>'
        );
    }
}
```

and in the `routes.yaml` file:

```
route1:
    path:       api/foo
    controller: LuckyController::number
    methods:    GET|POST
```

Using the php function `print_r(get_included_files())` I can see I am only using 20 include files for this new way, so much better, but I don't get anything returned to the browser when I go to the site: `http://www.myserver.org/api/foo`

I tried a couple other ways such as:

```
$foo_route = new Route('/api/foo', array('App\Http\Controllers\Api\V2\LuckyController' => 'number') );
```

Nothing I do seems to get Symfony to access the functions and return the results to the browser. What am I missing in the process?

Comment: Any error or access logs?

Comment: This approach has a quite a few gaps to be filled, which makes it hard to answer fully. Please check out the blog series "Build your own framework", especially [the routing section](https://symfony.com/doc/current/create_framework/routing.html) in the Symfony docs. It will give you a working example you can base your approach on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dbrumann had a much better link than I did. I had been going through the regular documentation section here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html instead of the Build Your Own Framework section: https://symfony.com/doc/current/create_framework/routing.html

Before I got his response I tried a different routing library Macaw (https://github.com/noahbuscher/macaw) which ended up being pretty simple and used much fewer include files.

In addition to the routing, I needed an autoloader since the controller files were outside the public directory, I chose `robot-loader`, so now my `minvendor.json` file looks like this:

```
{    
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "minvendor"
    },
    "require": {
        "noahbuscher/macaw": "dev-master",
        "nette/robot-loader": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

and a full working example page would look like this:

```
<?PHP
require __DIR__.'/../minvendor/autoload.php';
use \NoahBuscher\Macaw\Macaw;

$loader = new Nette\Loaders\RobotLoader;

// Add directories for RobotLoader to index
$loader->addDirectory(__DIR__ . '/../app/Http/Controllers/Api/V2');

// And set caching to the 'temp' directory
$loader->setTempDirectory(__DIR__ . '/temp');
$loader->register(); // Run the RobotLoader


//just a couple ways you can define routes
Macaw::get('/api/foo', function() {
  echo 'Hello world!';
});
Macaw::post('/api/bar', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\V2\Controller@accounting');

Macaw::dispatch();
```